# Group by possible null column, can't use null propagating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, null

Here is a left join of two tables.  On the line `g.rpt.Location` in the group by, `g.rpt` could be null, so I'm getting warned about dereferencing a possible null object.  ctx is a code first Entity Frameworks database.

```
var query = ctx.ObjTable
    .GroupJoin(ctx.RptTable, obj => obj.Upc,
        rpt => rpt.Upc,
        (obj, rpt) => new { obj, rpt })
    .SelectMany(j => j.rpt.DefaultIfEmpty(), (j, rpt) => new
        {
            j.obj, rpt,
        })
    .GroupBy(g => new
        {
            g.rpt.Location,  //Problem here
            g.obj.Category,
            g.obj.Desc,
        }
    .Select(s => new MyClass
    {
        Location = s.Key.Location,
        Category = s.Key.Category,
        Desc = s.Key.Desc,
        Total = s.Sum(x => x.rpt.Numeric),
    });
```

I tried `g.rpt?.Location` but that gives "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator."

tried `g.rpt == null ? null : g.rpt`.  Tried using ??.

Tried this, seemed far fetched but I tried...

```
.GroupBy(g => g.rpt == null 
    ? new
        {
            g.rpt.Location,
            g.obj.Category,
            g.obj.Desc,
        } 
    : new
        {
            g.obj.Category,
            g.obj.Descriptor,
        })
```

Comment: Try extracting Location and Numeric using the same techniques in the `j.obj, rpt,` line instead. Will it give you the same error?

Comment: Maybe in the select many at "j.rpt.DefaultIfEmpty()" I can somehow create a dummy record with empty values?

Comment: Why do you group (`GroupJoin`) then flatten the group (`SelectMany`) and then group again (`GroupBy`)? The `GroupJoin` gives you everything you need. Better still, use a navigation property `ObjTable.RptTables` and you don't even need any grouping.

Comment: Not my database.  Database has zero defined FK's and I'm not terribly familiar with it so setting up navigation properties seemed sketchy right now.  Maybe one Day.

As to why I'm flatting it, this is just a snippet, I'm actually left joining ~6 tables and then grouping the whole result, the infinitely nested lists when left joining so many tables were difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own default value in `DefaultOrEmpty`, e.g.

```cs
var defaultRpt = new Rpt {Location = "", Numeric = 0}

...
    .SelectMany(j => j.rpt.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultRpt), (j, rpt)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked, thanks to Mike Mozhaaev's comment.  Extract the values needed for the further operations in the SelectMany.

I wish I could choose two correct answers because the other answer he provided works too.

```
var query = ctx.ObjTable
    .GroupJoin(ctx.RptTable, obj => obj.Upc,
        rpt => rpt.Upc,
        (obj, rpt) => new { obj, rpt })
    .SelectMany(j => j.rpt.DefaultIfEmpty(), (j, rpt) => new
        {
            j.obj,
            Upc = rpt != null ? rpt.Upc : string.Empty,
            Numeric = rpt != null ? (int?)rpt.Numeric : null;
        })
    .GroupBy(g => new
        {
            g.Location,  //Problem here
            g.obj.Category,
            g.obj.Desc,
        }
    .Select(s => new MyClass
    {
        Location = s.Key.Location,
        Category = s.Key.Category,
        Desc = s.Key.Desc,
        Total = s.Sum(x => x.Numeric),
    });
```

EDIT:

Better/best answer, obvious in hindsight.  The problem with the ? : pattern is that it can't resolve a name for the field, so manually setting the name fixes it.

```
.GroupBy(g => new
    {
        Location = g.rpt == null ? null : g.rpt.Location,
        g.obj.Category,
        g.obj.Desc,
    }
```